# Spring-Batch/JPA : Share Persistence Context between reader,processor and writer

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch, entitymanager

We're on a Web application that have also batch processing.

We're facing performances problems. We're using Spring batch and JPA (with hibernate implementation), but no EJB's.

For the moment we're using a `HibernateCursorItemReader` to load the data and a `JPAItemWriter` to make updates.

I'm searching for a while for the best pattern to optimize our batch. I've seen many discussion and documentation where people unadvise to use extended persistence context for many problems like getting OutOfMemory error, non threadsafe object...

But in our case, we talk about a batch processing so there would only be one persistence context at one time. We planed to flush and clear the `EntityManager` after each chunk, wich will persist item one by one (commit size = 1).

So I don't see why not to use only one persistence context for the reader, processor and the writer. The idea is that it would avoid many select (at least one per item) to reattach detached item between reader and writer (so that `EntityManager` can merge without making another select).

So I'm wondering if you would have recommendation about this pattern.

And also how to implement it properly, because it is not the defaut behavior for Spring Batch. In fact we would have to override the persistence context property which is Transactional for the web application, and injected with the `@PersistenceContext` annotation.

Edit : I forget to say that we're on a Tomcat 7 server

Comment: Why are you even using a commit size of 1? That creates a lot of overhead in creating and destroying connections. The problem with sharing the context is problematic due to dirty checking, all the objects in the cache are checked before a select and also when commit. This can make your performance even worse.

Comment: Thanks for answer. We _planned_ to use commit size of 1 to force the writer to make flush and clear on the EntityManager and so to avoid growing cache of hibernate. I've read on Spring documentation that for Databasewriter they advise to do so : "This is a common use case, especially when using Hibernate, and the simple guideline for implementations of ItemWriter, is to flush on each call to write(). Doing so allows for items to be skipped reliably, with Spring Batch taking care internally of the granularity of the calls to ItemWriter after an error."

Comment: And i don't see why dirty checking would be more use than in non shared context. Because if we share it, there is just one select for the reader, and because the item are still attached, one udpate or insert in the writer. If we don't share we have to reattach the item in the writer and so that make dirty checking. Am I wrong ?

Comment: The `JpaItemWriter` already flushes, it doesn't clear but alas, just make sure your batch size isn't too large. Dirty checking is always done, the more objects you have in your first level cache the longer it takes. Also you aren't using an `EntityManger` for the read but a `Session` as you are mixing plain Hibernate and JPA.

Comment: Yes in fact we get the session from a SessionFactory obtain by type casting the EntityManagerFactory in HibernateEntityManagerFactory. The link between the session and the injected EntityManager seems to be kept by JPA since we doesn't have to reattach the item load with the session to use lazyloading on object. If I understand you well, dirty checking will be perform with or without shared persistence context, and we will have only one item (with its association) in the session to dirty check. So what do you think about our pattern and more important, how to do it properly ?

Comment: The main problem is, imho, that when the session gets corrupted you are basically gone. Normally that isn't a problem and reading proceeds and some items might not be written but everything continues now it might fail. Also I doubt if that it will really fix your problem or introduce new ones as you will get a lot of transaction overhead which in general is quite expensive. I strongly suggest investigation where the problems come from and fix that before changing a lot of things around.